# Fancybox and IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

A few problems utilising the latest version of Fancybox and IE8.

Firstly, the close button (top right) if half cut off (you only see the bottom left) - this happens on both the youtube videos and images.

Secondly when you close Fancybox, the screen remains black causing you to refresh the page again to see content - this only happens on youtube videos.

You can see an example of it working at:
http://www.braincells.com.au/jindowie/ (bottom middle panel, watch the video link)

Any assistance, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update to the latest source code - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master

Comment: Yes, but the last commit is ~10min ago :)

Comment: No difference - the close is still half cut off

Comment: Hmm, works fine for me - http://i.imgur.com/0Nai5.jpg Are you using the native IE8? What OS?

Comment: If you are using fancybox-media then try removing the class `fancybox.iframe`

Comment: Upgraded, and still no change - http://i.imgur.com/CmWDY.jpg

Comment: Also, since the latest version - the closing of the overlay is not working again (it was with the previous version), but the issue of the close button still remains

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is a tricky one.

I found one error that could lead to this. You don't close the div id `footer`. You could try to add a closing to this and check if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Still no luck guys, any other suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions? Since the latest version - the closing of the overlay is not working again (it was with the previous version), but the issue of the close button still remains